# Return number of arrays within a dictionary key?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

How do I return the number of arrays within a dictionary key?

```
var timedic = [String: [AnyObject]]()
```

output:
    `var output = ["March 27": ["do the dishes", "take out the trash"], ["Take bro to soccer practice"], "March 29": ["Walk the dog", "Water the plants"], "March 28": ["Clean the house"]]`

I tried `timedic["March 27"].count` but I get the number of objects inside the array instead of the number of arrays under the key "March 27"

Comment: Your dictionary maps a String to an Array of AnyObject.  If you wanted to have your key map to an Array of Arrays, you would need to do `var timedic = [String : [[AnyObject]]]()`

Comment: Your question is not clear. So given this input `["March 27": ["do the dishes", "take out the trash"], "March 29": ["Walk the dog", "Water the plants"], "March 28": ["Clean the house"]]` what output do you expect?

Comment: There is only 1 array under each key

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question example.

Comment: Then your data structure needs to change as per the comment and the answer. You are lacking a set of [] in each of your dictionary values now, but what you want is `[String:[[String]]]`. A dictionary with string keys and an array of string arrays as the value

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have your key map to an Array of Arrays, you would need to do this:

```swift
var timedic = [String : [[AnyObject]]]()
```

Which would map a String to an Array of Arrays of AnyObject. As it currently stands, your dictionary maps a String to an Array of AnyObject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question however given this dictionary

```
var timedic = [
    "March 27": ["do the dishes", "take out the trash"],
    "March 29": ["Walk the dog", "Water the plants"],
    "March 28": ["Clean the house"]
]
```

If you want the **total number of arrays** inside the dictionary

```
let count = timedic.values.count
```

If you want the **total** number of `String(s)` into the dictionary

```
let count = timedic.values.flatten().count
```

If you want the total number of `String(s)` for a given **key**

```
let count = timedic["March 27"].values.flatten().count
```